# How can I control 4 separate Motors from a single H-Bridge?

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, mosfet

I have an interesting problem.
I am trying to control 4 separate actuators at the same time so they lift at the same speed.
Each actuator has feedback and at max draw they pull 12v10A each. The h-bridge can handle that, but I am looking for a way to switch the h-bridge to whichever of the 4 is needing to move to catch up. They all use potentiometer feedback. Relays are too slow at switching so those are out.

Comment: Four relays should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is to use four separate H-bridges. It will be way easier to provide start/stop gating of the digital logic level signals that drive the inputs to the H-bridges than it will ever be to messing with the high power signals going to each motor.

The four H-bridges has the additional significant advantage of spreading out the high power drive across more circuits rather than stressing one circuit to much higher levels.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use 5 half-bridges. One high-current half bridge that stays on constantly high or low to determine the direction and one half-bridge that is PWM'd for each motor.

That's assuming the direction of all four motors is always the same.